# Access Application.MainWindow content in usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

In WPF application it is easy to access MainWindow content but how to do in usercontrol.

In WPF Application, if my MainWindow name is Window1 and i have to access its one of the string variable named CName from some other class in same application.

```
 Window1 ww = Application.Current.MainWindow as Window1;

 String reqstring = ww.CName ;
```

I want to do same thing in usecontrol too.

Assume my usercontrol name is ABCcontrol and first/main Class name is ABCconrolLib

```
namespace ABCcontrol
{

  public partial class ABCcontrolLib : UserControl
  {
    Public String CName = "ABC";

    //....

  }
 }
```

Now i want to access this CName in some other class of same usercontrol by using Application.Control.MainWindow or by some other similar way

Please help me out as this is my first UserControl in WPF

Comment: How and when are you setting this `CName` property in `UserControl`?

Comment: You want to access the Window inside UserControl in XAML code or code behind?

Comment: want to access window/content in code/ some other class function. I can very much access in WPF Application but not able to do same in user control.

Answer (score 2):

You can access Application.Current.MainWindow  because you have just one instance of MainWindow in your whole application so they defined it as a static property.
If you have the same characteristic for your users control (just you need to use a single instance of it in the whole application) you can define a static property there as well.
Something like :
then you can access name property like UserControl1.Instance.CName

```
 public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
        {
            public static UserControl1 Instance
            {
                get;
                private set;
            }
     Public String CName = "ABC";
            public UserControl1()
            {

                if (Instance != null)// there should be just one instance
                    throw new NotSupportedException();
                Instance = this;

                InitializeComponent();
            }
        }
```

---

if you get error then you do not have just one instance of your usercontrol, you have to define a List  and register each instance of your users controls there. Something like:

```
 public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {

        public UserControl1()
        {
            (App.Current as App).UserControl1List.Add(this);

            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
     public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            UserControl1List = new List<UserControl1>();
        }
        public List<UserControl1> UserControl1List
        {
            get;
           private set;
        }
    }
```

then you can reach to each instance like  (App.Current as App).UserControl1List[0]...
or you can use a dictionary for storing each UserControl there.

Comment: Thanks for efforts, but it is in multi threaded environment :( , it is giving error if i use same user control more than once

Comment: Look at the edited answer, here you are using a list inside your App class (or somewhere else) then you register each instance of your user control there